# Underlined Numbered Tabs in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, tabs, shortcut

I have noticed that some of the tabs in Android Studio are numbered and underlined: I'm not sure if it is the same with everyone, but mine are 0-Messages, 1-Project, 2-Favorites, 3 I couldn't find, 4-Run, 5-Debug, 6-Android Monitor, 7-Structure. My guess is that they are ways to shortcut, and I really want to be able to shortcut to the Project tab to hide and show it. My question is if anyone knows what these numbers are for, and if they are shortcuts how to use them?

Comment: Since I can't see the answer I posted... I have found that holding ctrl-tab and then the desired number is one way to open the desired tab. I have a mac.

Answer (score 0):

```
Shortcuts to open specific windows in android studio:
Alt + 1 :Show project structure
Alt + 2 :Show favorites
Alt + 6 :Show Android Monitor
Alt + 7 :Show Class Structure
Alt + 9 :Show version control
```

Else use "Ctrl+Tab" to open Switcher view. Use Tab key to navigate through each window(Holding Ctrl)